# Sharepoint Excel to Lock/Close at Specified Time

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I want to set up a Sharepoint Excel file that automatically locks or closes for all users except the owner (or other specified user) at a specified time.

I know there are VBAs to do this in Excel but this needs to function in the web browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to prevent other users from changing the file at the specified time or prevent users from even being able to read it at the specified time?

Comment: Either one would work! It's basically a shared file that everyone can edit but from 11:00am-12:00pm it needs to be closed or locked so that someone can take the info out of it and reset it for the next day.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you on, and what tools/options are you willing (or able) to explore? E.g., SharePoint Designer Workflows, PowerShell scripts, Windows Server scheduled tasks, timer jobs written in Visual Studio...

Comment: Sharepoint Designer Workflow would be the best route, if that is possible. Thanks so much!